# How to catch the control name that caused exception in C#?

Tags: c#, controls, try-catch

I have few text boxes that should allow a certain format, but when a user enters it in a wrong format in a textbox, I would like to catch the control name and clear the text of the textbox.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are checking the format, and what is generating the exception?

Comment: windows forms? I think you do not need to catch anything, you won't like to have any exception thrown what you are describing is called input validation.

Comment: I have few textboxes, And I have a panel with three radiobuttons(Decimal, Binary and Hex). I need to take only a byte in each text box and if a user inputs more that a byte lets say in binary "111100001", I get formating exception. So, to make everything simple I would like to just clear the control's text when such things occur.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the user input because it's not in a given format is very user-unfriendly. What if only one of ten characters was wrong? They'd have to type it all over again. Just use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) with a `Mask` for the pattern you expect.

When using a `MaskedTextBox`, you can subscribe to the `MaskInputRejected` event as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx):

```
public void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ... // Other initialization code
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
    maskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected += new MaskInputRejectedEventHandler(maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected)
}

void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Input";
    toolTip1.Show("We're sorry, but only digits (0-9) are allowed in dates.", maskedTextBox1, maskedTextBox1.Location, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I really like that but I have three formats in one textbox(decimal, binary and Hex).

Comment: These are the max available values i am looking for:
Binary => 11111111
Hex => ff
Decimal => 255
Is it doable in Maskd text box, especially setting the decimal max value seemed harder for me when I tried.

Comment: Parse the input in the `KeyPress` event and try to parse the input. If it's incorrect you can set `e.Handled` to true, so it won't be entered in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks CodeMaster! much helpful. I will try this one now.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exceptions for expected behaviour is never right as they are very expensive.  If you need to see where the exception originated just check the top line of the stack trace.

Comment: How can I check the stack? I'm preety new to C#.

Answer (score 0):

**debug only**

you can get control name in debug mode from the yourForm.cs .  i dont think this code will run on relese cuz. the  source file wont be in ther release right?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public void ParseControlText()
{
    try
    {
        var doubleval = Double.Parse(tb_double.Text);
        var intval    = Int32.Parse(tb_int.Text);

        //... bunch of controls need to be parssed to calculate  something

    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        var stlast = new StackTrace(ex,true).GetFrames().Last();

       //this requires   form.cs to exist . how am i gonna do this in release? idk
        var stLine = File.ReadLines(stlast.GetFileName())
            .ToList()[stlast.GetFileLineNumber()-1];
        var m = Regex.Match(stLine ,@"\((.*?)\..*?\)"); 
        var ctrlname = m.Groups[1].Value;

        MessageBox.Show( ctrlname + " control's text coundnt be Parsed! " );

    }

}
```